# What is a better equivalent of this sentence?

Tags: sentence, writing-style, diction

The sentence goes so:

> I sit in my room, in a house that belongs to me alone.

The goal of the sentence is to say that the speaker is in a house that belongs to him only and to no one else. The other goal is to show a degree of sophistication and calmness in the speaker's diction. It is also meant to be a sentence in a diary.

Comment: If you're in a house that "alone belongs to me," the only thing you own is the house. You want to say "a house that belongs to me alone".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the sentence as it is.   Depending on the gloomy effect desired, maybe swap a few articles or pronouns.      "I sit in my room, in _the_ house that belongs to me alone.";        "I sit _within_ my room, in a house that _now_ belongs to me alone.";       "I sit, in my room, in this house that belongs to me alone.";      etc...

Comment: Correction: after reading the 1st draft, (which seems less glum than the revision suggested by Peter Shor), this: `I sit in my room, in a house that now belongs solely to me.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:  Here I sit in my room in a house that is all mine and only mine.

Comment: Please explain your answer in full.